# Node.js flash messages don't display on the page

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, flash-message

The code runs without getting any errors on my server terminal but I can't get the flash massage on the web page. This is my full code:

**passport.js**:

```
if(user) {
    return done(null, false, req.flash('emailmessage', 'That email is already taken') );
} else {
    var userPassword = generateHash(password);
    var data = {
        email:email,
        password:userPassword
    };
}
```

**auth.js**:

```
app.get('/signup', authController.signup,function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('signup',{message: req.flash('emailmessage')})
});

app.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
    successRedirect: '/dashboard',
    failureRedirect: '/signup',
    failureFlash : true
}));
```

**mysignup.hbs**:

```
{{emailmessage}}
<div id="frmCheckUsername">
    <form id="signup" name="signup" method="post" action="/signup">
    <p><label for="email">Email Address</label>
    <input class="text" name="email" type="email" id="email"  required class="demoInputBox" onBlur="checkAvailability()"/><span id="user-availability-status"></span></p>
    <p><label for="password">Password</label>
    <input name="password" type="password" required/></p>
    <input class="btn" name="signbtn" type="submit" id="signbtn" value="Sign Up" />
    </form>
    <span id="signspano" ></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Using flash messages requires a req.flash() function. You can use the [flash](https://github.com/expressjs/flash) middleware.

Comment: @YiKai i have already var flash = require('connect-flash');

Comment: And session middleware too? Flash middleware requires session middleware to work.

Comment: @YiKai i tested my flash with simple hello world example and that's worked but in this passport signup redirection not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code uses `message` as variable:

```
res.render('signup',{message: req.flash('emailmessage')})
```

But your template uses `emailmessage`:

```
{{emailmessage}}
```